# NFS Mounts in Puppet - Return code 32 (mount.nfs: is busy or already mounted)

Tags: redhat, nfs, puppet

We are using puppet to manage our NFS mounts on RHEL 6.1

Puppet is able to successfully mount the NFS mounts during boot time, after that every time puppet reloads, it tries to mount the already existing mounts and fails with a return code 32.

It's almost that puppet thinks that the mounts are not present and tries executing the the mount commands again

Any pointer to resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you provide the following?  Log output from Puppet, the resource from your manifests, the output of `mount` and `puppet resource mount` (for the NFS mount).  It could be a problem matching up the mounted NFS filesystem to the resource.

Comment: I've seen this happen if the mount resources have trailing slashes on them.  When puppet (happens with init scripts too) does a grep on the mount output or /proc/mounts they don't have the slash, leading the caller to think it's not mounted.

Comment: This error is a puppet bug which is not yet fixed. Hopefully they will fix it in the future release

Answer (score 1):

I just bumped into this trying to remount an NFS filesystem with different mount options, and Chef. Neither Puppet nor Chef are to blame; after all, `mount.nfs` is returning a 32.

```
10.120.18.15:/data/chocolate /data/chocolate nfs rw,intr,noatime,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576 0 2
10.120.18.15:/data/vanilla /data/vanilla nfs rw,intr 0 2

root@x:~# mount -o remount,rw,intr /data/chocolate
root@x:~# echo $?
32
```

One of those options causes the RC of 32.  I just unmounted, mounted with only `rw,intr` and now Chef runs cleanly every time.

Answer (score -1):

This is caused by Puppet or Chef not checking that the mount already exists before attempting to remount.  Or due to load balancers returning a different IP Address causing mount to see it as a new mount point.  Puppet/Chef needs to do better error checking on this scenario.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1468013

Comment: The link is not accessible for everyone.